# Call notification from another class

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

Given that in my application I need many notifications I have a class like that.

```
public class MyNotificationClass{

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
    Context context;

    static final int NOTIFICA1 = 1;
    static final int NOTIFICA2 = 2;

    public MyNotificationClass(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    }

    public void mostra(int Id) {

        switch(Id)
        {
        case NOTIFICA1:
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Text01");
            notificationBuilder.setContentText("Text01");
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICA1, notificationBuilder.build());
            break;
        case NOTIFICA2:
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Text02");
            notificationBuilder.setContentText("Text02");
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICA2, notificationBuilder.build());
            break;
        }
        notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS );
    }

}
```

If I wanted to call, for example, the notification number 1. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `setWhen(), setSmallIcon(), setDefaults()` on the NotificationBuilder before you `build()` the Notification. Move that code in front of the switch-block.

**The important call is** `setSmallIcon()`. If you don't set an icon the notification will not be shown.

Try it like this:

```
public void mostra(int Id) {

    notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS );

    switch(Id)
    {
    case NOTIFICA1:
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Text01");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Text01");
        mNotificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
        break;
    case NOTIFICA2:
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Text02");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Text02");
        mNotificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Call this method like this in your Activity:

```
MyNotificationClass myNoti = new MyNotificationClass(this);
myNoti.mostra(MyNotificationClass.NOTIFICA1);
```

Comment: Okay thanks but to invoke the notifica1 how can I do?

Comment: @MarioG. I edited my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Into mostra method i put   mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
But my app crash at this line with a null pointer. Why?

Comment: @MarioG. Have you assigned the paramater context in your constructor to the field context?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String title = remoteMessage.getFrom();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String imageUri;
        Bitmap picture;

        if (remoteMessage.getData().get("image") != null) {

            imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
            picture = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);

        } else {

            picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.bg);

        }

        // This below code is for display image in notificaation
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        notiStyle.setSummaryText(body);
        notiStyle.bigPicture(picture);


        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
                0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setStyle(notiStyle);


        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            assert mNotificationManager != null;
            mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
        assert mNotificationManager != null;

        mNotificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt() /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());


    }


---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Call this method like this in your Activity:

MyFirebaseMessagingService myfirebasemsg = new MyFirebaseMessagingService();
myfirebasemsg.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
```